# How should I authenticate a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, google-api, smtp

so according to Google's security page, the ability to allow unsecured third party apps will be removed in a few months (I understand why they are doing this, however), this creates a small inconvenience for a "report a bug" feature of my app, maybe I misunderstand the API but if I do NOT plan to release my app on the official Google stores, but rather offer it on my own website people can download (in most cases, I personally know 95% of the people downloading this file), how can I authenticate it so I can still use SMTP to essentially send mail to myself through a WinForms application? If I setup a OAuth2.0 "test" account, I have to give it a list of google accounts that can use the app, being myself since I want to send to and through my own account, as my app - but anyone who downloads the app, has to log into my Google account to allow the authentication, their own guides suggest to download the token file it generate and use that in the app

The way my app works currently: users can write a description and type a message that send a SMTP email to my gmail, from my gmail (with credentials in the app), so no log-in required from the user, it all happens "automagically" and I dont want to force users to log into a google account just to tell me what feature of the app isnt working as intended - hopefully this makes sense, I can try to provide more details if needed, here is my current code, in c#:

```
void SendReport(bool isFeedback, string context)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpServer.Port = 587;
        smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myGMAILAcc", "myPass...");
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();
        msgMail.From = new MailAddress("myGMAILAcc");
        msgMail.To.Add("myGMAILAcc");

        msgMail.Subject = "App" + (isFeedback ? " Feedback" : " Bug Report");
        msgMail.Body = context;
        msgMail.IsBodyHtml = false;

        smtpServer.Send(msgMail);
        msgMail.Dispose();

        MessageBox.Show("Report sent!");
    }
```

This currently works exactly as intended - user clicks a button, form window pops up, they type some words, choose if it is "feedback/suggestion" or a "bug" and click another button that calls this function, a few seconds later "report sent!" - in a few months when Google changes the security, this wont work anymore, so I guess im wondering how to keep it working without it throwing a "authentication" error due to the "allow third party apps" no longer being supported by Google, or maybe some other service or way I can achieve my end result? Being, "user can quickly and easily send me a email with a body of text"

Comment: I don't know how many privacy laws this breaks. You basically give everyone full access to your email account where they can send emails from and read everyone's emails. Reverse engineering a Winforms App takes zero effort. You might as well write your login data into a label in the form for them to log into your account.

Comment: What would you suggest? It seems like every app has a way to easily send a email to the developers through the app with no login required from the user, I figured sending a Gmail to myself would be a easy and free way of doing this with just a simple SMTP call - if my app can be reverse engineered anyway, wouldnt that render any solution completely irrelevant for anyone ambitious enough to try? Are there alternatives to SMTP if its not secure or viable?

Comment: I think you might be barking up the wrong dog but the absolute easiest way to fix up a functionality where the user can click a button and get an email window up is to Process.Start a mailto link. You might be better overall though dispensing with the mail bit, put a server up that accepts an api call and sends it on, then you do away with all this imposition of someone else's rules

Comment: check out xoauth2 option with the SMTP server

Comment: @user18789895 if you already have a website then just create an extra site where the user can fill out a form to send you feedback. Now it's very easy in C# to just create a POST Request to your website to automatically trigger that form.

Comment: Interesting, im not sure how the API approach would work, but I think a POST request might be a good alternative for me to look into, thank you for providing some insight into this